# Visual select single column from cursor to last line with text in column

Tags: visual-mode, cursor-motions

There are already a lot of similar questions to this.

- [Jump to last line, but stay in the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748161/jump-to-last-line-but-stay-in-the-same-column)
- [How to go to the end of the file in vim while preserving the current column under the cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16631436/how-to-go-to-the-end-of-the-file-in-vim-while-preserving-the-current-column-unde)
- [How do you select a whole column in visual block mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736678/how-do-you-select-a-whole-column-in-visual-block-mode)

They all end with toggling the `startofline` setting. Using `startofline` it's possible to start a visual selection with `Ctrl-v` and then use `gg` or `G` to select entire columns of text from the cursor to the beginning or to the end of the file. What if I want to select an entire column that doesn't go to the beginning or end of the file?

So for this text:

```
first line

x b c
a m w
q y c
a e z

last line
```

If the cursor was on `b` in the line reading `x b c`, how can I select the column starting at that b and ending on the `e` in `a e z`?

For non-column oriented actions similar to this I would use the shift paren/bracket family but they seem unaffected by `nostartofline`.

Comment: Something like this, perhaps: https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim

Comment: @VanLaser That comment sure sounds like an answer.

Comment: Ok, I added an answer based on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the simplest way to solve this (apart from using something like `ctrl-v 4j`) is to use the [textojb-word-column](https://github.com/coderifous/textobj-word-column.vim) plugin: if cursor is placed on the "right" column, a simple `vic` will get the job done. This is the demo from the plugin page:

[image: gif demo from the plugin page]